# Magento2 The entity that was requested doesn't exist

Tags: magento2

i am trying to create object of class

**Magento\Braintree\Model\Adapter\BraintreeAdapter**

when i creating object like

```
$this->adapter = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create('Magento\Braintree\Model\Adapter\BraintreeAdapter');
```

it gives error **The entity that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the entity and try again.**

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

```
$config = [
    'merchantId' => '',
    'publicKey' => '',
    'privateKey' => '',
    'environment' => ''
];

$this->adapter = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create('Magento\Braintree\Model\Adapter\BraintreeAdapter', $config);
```